# Firebase: FCM: payload syntax for Android/iOS collapsable and non-collapsable notifications

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to find the correct syntax and specific payload keys to achieve collapsable and non-collapsable notifications on iOS, and non-callapsable notifications on Android. I've got collapsable working on Android, so I know I'm moving in the right direction.

I am using the admin.messaging().send(payload) function in my Node.js Cloud Functions file.

My collapsable payload example:

```
{
  notification: {
    title: `${userName}`,
    body: `${message.msg}`
  },
  data: {
    click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    v_type: 'chatMsg',
    v_uid: uid,
    v_cid: cid,
  },
  android: {
    collapse_key: cid,
  },
  apns: {
    headers: {
      'apns-collapse-id': cid,
    }
  },
  token: tokenDoc.data().notificationToken,
}
```

For non collapsable messages I use the 'apns-id' key instead of 'apns-collapse-id'. I'm not sure what the equivalent is for android. The documentation on Firebase covers these keys, but there is no example of how the payload structure should look.

Firebase documentation states that messages are non collapsable by default, but how does the device know when to replace an existing notification related to the same information? I assume I have to set an id for the device to know to overwrite an existing notification.